# parallel downloads in PHP

Tags: php, download, parallel-processing

I want to download (or simply  file_get_contents) for 5 places. I wait say 1.2 sec for each that means in total 1.2X5=6 seconds. I want to save waiting time. I thought I could wait 1.3 sec is enough. How can I approach?

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want to download something in your script, or offer something for download?  Then I don't understand what you want to do with the timing

Comment: I think he wants his script to download 5 files in parallel.

Comment: can you execute command line programs?

Comment: @Pekka never mind timing. Yes I can execute but wont prefer any way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [**curl_multi_***](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) functions to achieve parallel downloads.

Answer (score 2):

this is possible but only by creating multiple threads outside PHP

With PHP scripts run in a single thread, meaning that it can only do 1 task at a time, the only way you can do this with PHP is by creating / using an external application installed / placed on your server and using exec to do this and waiting for a response from the exec, or using the fork_* functions to be able to dip and dive in and out of threads.

Answer (score 1):

To get you started you can run the downloads in parallel by forking them into the background using php's popen: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/multicurl-library/

btw. you're looking for non blocking connections.